# ssd no more working after installing debian

Tags: debian, disk, ssd

I feel stupid. This afternoon I installed debian on my external ssd (samsung T7) and I realised I didnt need to. But the problem is that I want to use it like a normal external ssd to store my games and big files but the ssd is considered as a boot disk or smth like this and i can't use it.
What should I do ?

Comment: You can create a fresh partition table, and then a partition with the file system you want. I think it is easiest with `gparted`, a Linux tool with a graphical user interface, if you have Linux with a graphical desktop environment. (You may need to install `gparted`.) Which Linux distro are you running? Or are you running Windows? In that case you let Windows format it.

Comment: Why do you think that using an external ssd as a boot disk would prevent you from using it for storage? Please [edit] your question to address this. Include error messages or other detail

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main PC is a Mac or Windows, reformat the SSD to exFAT file format. On macOS this is as simple as a right-click and click 'Format'.
If your main PC is Linux, then find the location of the drive when plugged in with `lsblk`, then wipe it with the `dd if=/dev/zero` command, and then if it is still in the wrong file system reformat it to ext4.